# Google Tagmanager claims regex does not match

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I want to fire the tagmanager when the cookie-Consent button is beeing clicked.
Problem is: The Tagmanager is claiming that the regex is not giving a result. I tried to veryfy it in different regex testing tool. It IS a match. Why is the tagmanager not verifying the regex match?

Tagmanager Debugging view with failed regex match

[image: 1]

regular expression:

```
js-cookie-accept-all-button|js-offcanvas-cookie-accept-all|js-offcanvas-cookie-submit
```

String:

```
HTMLButtonElement: html > body.is-ctl-navigation.is-act-index > div.cookie-permission-container > div.container > div.row.align-items-center > div.col-12.col-md-auto.pr-2 > span.js-cookie-accept-all-button > button.btn.btn-primary
```

Answer (score 1):

In GTM, element is not a string. It's an element. An element can't match a regex. Only strings match regexes.

What you really want to do here is to have `{{Click Element}}` Match a CSS Selector `span.js-cookie-accept-all-button>button.btn.btn-primary`